# How to Speed Up data retrieval from mongodb in node.js

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a d3-node.js-mongodb pipeline setup for visualizing data in mongo db.
I have a data table which is around 1 gb in size. The visualization takes around 20 seconds to load and the api also takes the same amount of time to show the fetched data.

**Is there some method by which i can speed this up?**

I tried using pm2 but i got no performance gain and also no matter what i did, it would always run my app in fork mode. I am running node version .12 on a windows machine.

Thank you.
Anmol

Comment: After a restart pm2 is indeed running my app in cluster mode. But there is no improvement in the time taken to fetch data. Will node cluster module deployment help? Does enabling multi threaded improve my data fetching rate as well?

Comment: if you have not had indexes already, use index on your search keys on Mongo collection. If the result set is reasonable size, use 'covered index/query', meaning have index for both search params and result params.

Answer (score 0):

Be shure to start your node process in production mode:

```
NODE_ENV=production pm2 restart <process_id> --update-env
```